# how to Organize a program into header and c files

Tags: c

I am required to organize the following c code into header (s) and c file (s). However, im unable to do so myself.

The code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 256
#define PROGRAMMES_SIZE 2
#define DELIMETER ","

struct programme
{
    char name[32];
    char code[8];
    int credits;
};

struct programme parseProgramme(char *);
struct programme createProgramme(char[], char[], int);
void printProgramme(struct programme);
void updateProgrammeName(struct programme *, char[]);

int main()
{
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    struct programme programmes[PROGRAMMES_SIZE];

    FILE *input = fopen("input", "r");

    if (input == NULL)
        exit(1);

    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < PROGRAMMES_SIZE; i++)
    {
        fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, input);
        programmes[i] = parseProgramme(buffer);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < PROGRAMMES_SIZE; i++)
        printProgramme(programmes[i]);

    fclose(input);

    return 0;
}

struct programme parseProgramme(char *buffer)
{
    char name[32];
    char code[8];
    int credits;

    // parse name
    strcpy(name, strtok(buffer, DELIMETER));

    // parse code
    strcpy(code, strtok(NULL, DELIMETER));

    // parse credits
    credits = atoi(strtok(NULL, DELIMETER));

    return createProgramme(name, code, credits);
}

struct programme createProgramme(char name[], char code[], int credits)
{
    struct programme programme;

    strcpy(programme.name, name);
    strcpy(programme.code, code);
    programme.credits = credits;

    return programme;
}

void printProgramme(struct programme programme)
{
    puts(programme.name);
    puts(programme.code);
    printf("%d\n", programme.credits);
}

void updateProgrammeName(struct programme *programme, char name[])
{
    strcpy(programme->name, name);
}
```

Please be noted that its not required to update any of the following definitions or implementations of the code listed above, stated by my collage professor. Just to organize them accordingly, any help is apricated!.

Comment: Put everything from lines 5-19 into a `programme.h` file and replace it with `#include "programme.h"`

Comment: @kaylum, +1 for not including the `#include`'s inside the header file. It is a good programming style, since the header file does not depend on the includes.

Comment: What did you try? How exactly did it fail?

Comment: @Yunnosch, it did not fail....I just don't understand how to organize it into a header and so on

Comment: I sort of disagree with @kaylum and debruss. The comments are oversimplifying. I have added an answer to better explain some of the nuances.

Answer (score 0):

There is no strict need to create a separate header file here, because there is no code re-use.

However, if some of the code were to be reused in other files, then it would start to make sense. So let's say we want to move some functionality to a library.

Then it would make sense to split up the functions to a separate file, and create a header file which would also be roughly representing the API.

So let's skip some code and look at `main.c`:

```
int main()
{
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    struct programme programmes[PROGRAMMES_SIZE];

    FILE *input = fopen("input", "r");

    if (input == NULL)
        exit(1);

    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < PROGRAMMES_SIZE; i++)
    {
        fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, input);
        programmes[i] = parseProgramme(buffer);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < PROGRAMMES_SIZE; i++)
        printProgramme(programmes[i]);

    fclose(input);

    return 0;
}
```

And obviously the functions would be in e.g. `program.c`:

```
struct programme parseProgramme(char *buffer)
{
    char name[32];
    char code[8];
    int credits;

    // parse name
    strcpy(name, strtok(buffer, DELIMETER));

    // parse code
    strcpy(code, strtok(NULL, DELIMETER));

    // parse credits
    credits = atoi(strtok(NULL, DELIMETER));

    return createProgramme(name, code, credits);
}

struct programme createProgramme(char name[], char code[], int credits)
{
    struct programme programme;

    strcpy(programme.name, name);
    strcpy(programme.code, code);
    programme.credits = credits;

    return programme;
}

void printProgramme(struct programme programme)
{
    puts(programme.name);
    puts(programme.code);
    printf("%d\n", programme.credits);
}

void updateProgrammeName(struct programme *programme, char name[])
{
    strcpy(programme->name, name);
}
```

Now we can easily see, that `PROGRAMMES_SIZE` and `BUFFER_SIZE` are not used in the functions, and should be defined in `main.c`.

On the other hand, `DELIMETER` is only used in the functions, so it should be defined at the top in `program.c`.

We can move the struct and function definitions to `program.h`. It's good practice to prevent recursive inclusion, we could use some simple `ifndef` for that:

```
#ifndef PROGRAM_H
#define PROGRAM_H

struct programme
{
    char name[32];
    char code[8];
    int credits;
};

struct programme parseProgramme(char *);
struct programme createProgramme(char[], char[], int);
void printProgramme(struct programme);
void updateProgrammeName(struct programme *, char[]);

#endif /* PROGRAM_H */
```

Finally, you should look which standard library functions are used in either `.c` file and add the necessary `#include` at the top of `main.c` and `program.c`. For example, `main.c` uses `fgets` and `program.c` uses `puts`. So both should `#include <stdio.h>`.

I'll leave the rest for you as an exercise.